# Put text just to the right of youtube iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm very new to HTML and CSS.
I want to put some text to just right of the youtube `iframe`.
I have tried this code

```css
.text {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<iframe width="200" height="100" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<span class="text">Hello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some text</span>
```

But this starts the text from the new line. I would like to start the text from the top right space of the iframe.
Please help me how to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ;)

Comment: Thanks it was my first question and I got the exact and quick answer for which I was looking :)

Answer (score 2):

Give `width` to `.text`.

```css
.text {
  float: right;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<iframe width="200" height="100" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<span class="text">Hello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some textHello This is some text</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do this http://jsfiddle.net/ak8u7k3n/

```
iframe {
  float: left;
}
```

and remove `float:right;` from `.text`

Comment: But what happens when his resolution is 768px? In either sense he didn't even accept the answer (which @Ravi you should if its the answer you need) but you changed the element dimensions and really IMHO set this up for repeat questions into the issue. It'd be better if the OP would read rules and element layout fundamentals, especially trying use a span as a block element it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first we have a fundamental issue. I know your a beginner so I'll explain.

1 AND THIS IS IMPORANT
The iframe is fixed width so I don't know your full implementation plan but it looks like you want to do a 2 column design. Simply floating one element won't do this.

You'll need to create 3 elements: 1 as a wrapper, 1 as a left column, 1 as a right column

2nd AND THIS IS IMPORTANT
A span tag is an inline declaration not a block-line and generally is used solely in block-line declarations such as:

```
<div>
<span>my text</span>Text with out span rules
</div>
```

Without working on the live project I couldn't give exactly the solution but here's the debugging method

1) Use a block-line element above the iframe.
1a) If your intending for the element to overlap the iframe the you'll need to also use the margin rule

```
margin: topValue rightValue bottomValue leftValue;
```

2) If you need the text to also be right aligned use the text-align: value; rule

3) If the text is behind the iframe when moved you will need to used the z-index: value; rule

SIDENOTE: Your class is "text" or .text in CSS syntax. This doesn't affect the text-alignment. For this you would need text-alignment also. Because you're only using float it will only affect the element not the node inside the element.